# Use Symfony expression to populate default route parameters

Tags: symfony

I have route like this:

```
os_user_security_check:
    pattern: /login_check
    host:     "{subdomain}.%base_host%"
    defaults:
        _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check
        subdomain: "expr(request.get('subdomain'))"
    requirements:
        _method: POST
        subdomain: "[a-z0-9\-_]+?"
```

What I want, is by default populate `subdomain` by default to prevent to affect it when generating the route, how ?